# Send HTML email using PHP with form data

Tags: php, html, email

Edited to try and make this read easier!

My company sends out HTML Emails, and I've ben instructed to create a "send to a friend" feature, because aparantly the "Forward" button isn't enough!

So, the user clicks the "send to a friend" link, which takes them to a web page. The url is actually a query string that captures the users name and email, to save them time, and also the URL of the web version of the HTML email:

```
send-to-a-friend.php/?sendersName=Drew&sendersEmail=name@gmail.com&webVersionURL=http://website.address/page.html
```

So I've got sendersName, sendersEmail and also webVersionURL to play with. Great.

I then have a form where this user can type in a name and email address of the intended recipient - recipientName and recipientEmail.

What I need to do is send the email when the form has been filled in. At the moment the code I have below sends it as soon as the page is loaded, which is not correct.

I do not know how to wrap the send email in a function that only sends once the form has been filled in, can anyone help with this part in particular?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>test send to a friend</title>
    </head>

    <body>

     <p>Who do you want to send this email to?</p>
    <form method="get" action="">
         <input type="text" id="recipientName" value="" name="recipientName" />
         <input type="text" id="recipientEmail" value="Email" name="recipientEmail" />
         <?php
             $_POST['recipientName'];
             $_POST['recipientEmail'];
         ?>
         <input type="submit" />
     </form>

     <hr />

     <p>This is what your message will look like:</p>
     <hr />
     <p>Hi <strong>RECIPIENT</strong>, your friend <strong><?php echo $_GET["sendersName"]; ?></strong> (<?php echo $_GET["sendersEmail"]; ?>) thought you might be interested in this email from shelter!</p>
     <p>------</p>
    <p>
    From: <?php echo $_GET["sendersName"]; ?> <br />
    Sent: <?php date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); $date = date('d/m/Y h:i a', time()); echo $date; ?><br />
    To: <strong>RECIPIENT</strong><br />
    Subject: FWD: <strong>Subject Line</strong><br />
    </p>

    <iframe src="<?php echo $_GET["webVersionURL"]; ?>" width="700" height="400"></iframe>


    <?php

    $to = $recipientEmail;

    // subject
    $subject = "Test mail";

    // message
    $message = file_get_contents($_GET["webVersionURL"]);

    // from
    $from = "".$_GET["sendersName"]."<".$_GET["sendersEmail"].">";

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers
    $headers .= "From:" . $from;

    // Mail it
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    echo "Mail Sent.";
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You should use a library like Swift Mailer to do that. That will free you from dealing with bunch of headers, well-known encoding issues and the stuff like that. So that you can focus on sending logic itself

Comment: I don't think I really need a library - as I only need to handle this one task.

Plus - I want to learn a bit more about PHP, hence I'd rather do this from scratch.

Comment: This looks super vulnerable to several kinds of injection.. a cookie for hackers and spammers. Yummy

Comment: I know, I'm learning one step at a time. I just need to know how to get this to work as step one, then I'll look at sessions and whatever.

Answer (score 0):

When you post your form the GET values from the form will overwrite those that were originally sent through so your sendersEmail and sendersName will be NULL.

You should store the html for your email as a variable so you can pass it into the mail function. Not sure what you are trying to do with the iframe??

Comment: recipientName and sendersName are two different things, as are recipientEmail and sendersEmail.

Comment: Th iframe is just to show the user what it is they will be sending.

Comment: Not sure I understand the process completely but I edited my answer

Comment: Edited my question, because it really didn't read right! Hope that's easier to understand now.